# Set default printer using power shell in Java

Tags: java, powershell, printing

I have the following problem. I would like to print my docx output automatically using power shell commands in Java.

So far I am using this snippet to print

```
private static void printOut() throws IOException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String command = "powershell Start-Process –FilePath  \"" + yourDocXPath + "\" –Verb Print";
        System.out.println(command);
        Process proc = runtime.exec(command);
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
    }
```

Is there a command I can insert in order to set the default printer(by name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add these codes to get the default printer in java:

```
PrintService defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
String printerName = defaultPrinter.getName();
```

Edit:

Use this powershell command to set the printer and print:

```
String command = "powershell Set-Printer –Name \"" + printerName + "\" -KeepPrintedJobs $true; powershell Start-Process –FilePath \"" + yourDocXPath + "\" –Verb Print";
```

Comment: Okay, so this gives me the name of the current default printer. But how do i alter it to the printer i want?

Comment: you want to get the default printer name and add it to the command right?

Comment: I would like to be able to set the default printer using power shell commands. Since there are many printers in this office, i want to be able to set the printer according to the department the user is working in.

Comment: According to what i understood..your command should print from the default printer...or you want to change the printer from where you want to print?

Comment: I want to be able to change it. Sometimes files have to be printed out in other departments and for these cases i need to be able to select another printer other than the default one.

Comment: Then you need to use this code to set the default printer:
`Set-Printer –Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" -KeepPrintedJobs $true`

Comment: Could you please tell me, how to include that into my command in Java? Sorry, i am completely new to PowerShell commands and how they interact with other commands ( and Java).

Comment: you can use it this way:
`String command = "powershell Set-Printer –Name \"" + printerName + "\" -KeepPrintedJobs $true; powershell Start-Process –FilePath  \"" + yourDocXPath + "\" –Verb Print";`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does this hold true while using Server 08 and / or Windows 7?